# How do I write a query to join three tables?

Tags: sql-server, join

I have to join three tables :

Case Data Table - has a unique row for each Case number
Metric Table - may have multiple rows for a Case number
Task SLA Table - may have multiple rows for a Case number

I have to join these in a way that I do not get any replication of rows in the final table.

The final table should have rows with unique Case Numbers and all columns from the Case Data Table,
'Created' column for each case from Metric Table,
and the 'Elapsed time' and 'Time Left' columns of the SLA Table.

But to remove duplication, we must pick only one record from the Metric and SLA Tables.

The criteria to pick this record for each case is :

Metric Table - pick the minimum of 'Created' date for each Case.

Task SLA Table - pick the values of 'Elapsed time' and 'Time Left' corresponding to the maximum value of 'Start Date' for each case.

I was able to achieve the first join using the following query (The join was created between Case Data and Metric tables using SUBSTRING because there was 'Case :' appended before the Case numbers in the Metric table) :

```
    SELECT cd.Number, cd.Channel, cd.[State], cd.[Priority], cd.[Affected User], cd.Organization, 
    cd.Contact, cd.Client, cd.Product, cd.Category, cd.Subcategory, cd.[Ticket Summary], cd.[Case Type], 
    cd.[Case Aging], cd.Resolved, cd.Closed, cd.[Follow up], cd.Opened, cd.[Made SLA], cd.[SLA due], cd.[Schedule Follow Up],
    cd.[Resolution code], cd.[L2/L3 User], cd.Updated,

    Min(Created) AS 'First Response' FROM [dbo].[Support Dashboard Case Data] cd 

JOIN [dbo].[Metric Data] md ON cd.Number = SUBSTRING(md.ID,7,LEN(md.ID)) 

group by   cd.Number, cd.Channel, cd.[State], cd.[Priority], cd.[Affected User], cd.Organization, 
    cd.Contact, cd.Client, cd.Product, cd.Category, cd.Subcategory, cd.[Ticket Summary], cd.[Case Type], 
    cd.[Case Aging], cd.Resolved, cd.Closed, cd.[Follow up], cd.Opened, cd.[Made SLA], cd.[SLA due], cd.[Schedule Follow Up],
    cd.[Resolution code], cd.[L2/L3 User], cd.Updated
```

How do I incorporate the second join here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use row_number()

```
select * from
(
SELECT cd.Number, cd.Channel, cd.[State], cd.[Priority], cd.[Affected User], cd.Organization, 
    cd.Contact, cd.Client, cd.Product, cd.Category, cd.Subcategory, cd.[Ticket Summary], cd.[Case Type], 
    cd.[Case Aging], cd.Resolved, cd.Closed, cd.[Follow up], cd.Opened, cd.[Made SLA], cd.[SLA due], cd.[Schedule Follow Up],
    cd.[Resolution code], cd.[L2/L3 User], cd.Updated,Created 'First Response',row_number() over(partition by cd.number order by created desc) as rn
FROM [dbo].[Support Dashboard Case Data] cd 
JOIN [dbo].[Metric Data] md ON cd.Number = SUBSTRING(md.ID,7,LEN(md.ID)) 
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: Is this how I create the second join? If yes, how do I add it to the first one?